# Still logged in even after clearing browser data

Tags: bug, login

Before closing my browser on a shared computer, I usually clear the browser data. On StackExchange, I am still logged after clearing my data.

- open https://superuser.com/users/login
- log in with google
- visit http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access
- click login link on bottom ( http://chat.stackexchange.com/login/global?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fchat.stackexchange.com%2frooms%2f118%2froot-access )
- Now I'm logged in on chat
- Open an empty tab and close all other tabs
- press ctrl+shift+del
- mark every checkbox and clear all data
- visit gmail, not logged in
- visit superuser.com, is not logged in but gets recognized and auto logged in
- visit http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access, is already logged in
- visit https://superuser.com/users/logout and clicks logout
- stops being autologged on superuser.com
- is not logged in anymore on http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access

FF 20.0 on Win 7 Pro 32bits pt-br. Issue doesn't happen if I log in using Stack Exchange id. Doesn't happen on Chrome Win. Doesn't happen on FF 20 on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Should this question be moved to SU?

Answer (score 1):

It could be an issue of that particular brower/version/OS combination you were using. *Is anyone else able to reproduce this bug locally?*

As a troubleshooting step can you verify that the issue still happens if you make sure you select "Everything" as "Time range to clear"?

[image]

Comment: I have already tried that, no success.

Comment: @ruda.almeida: Are you *sure* you set the time range to Everything as shown above? Although I'm not sure whether SE uses DOM storage (localStorage/sessionStorage) and can't check ATM, if it does then I believe [the only way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#Storage_location_and_clearing_the_data) to clear such persistent data is by clearing everything.

Comment: I'm 99.999999% sure. I can only check on tuesdays and thursdays, will double-check tomorrow morning.

Comment: @ruda.almeida uh, are we missing something here?  **You might want to clarify why you can only check this on Tuesdays/Thursdays**...  This is almost certainly an issue with your browser software (perhaps you lack permissions to erase files in a certain computer's temporary directory?) as the only way the website would know it was *you* would be when *you* request the website with *your* session ID.

Comment: I'd guess it would be a lack of physical access to the system